# FindBy combining 'between' and 'or'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm already using `findAllDateBetween(startD, endD)` but I would like to know if I can include another date field to search for. Something like (is not working) `findAllDate1BetweenOrDate2Between(startD, endD)`. The startD and endD are the same for Date1 and Date2. Any ideas?

This is the repository:

```
public interface Cert10TotalRepository extends JpaRepository<Cert10Total, Integer> {
    List<Cert10Total> findByDateGermBetween(Date start, Date end);
}
```

I would like to add `OrDatePurityBetween (Date start, Date end)`

Thank you

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: I updated it. Not sure if that is enough...

Comment: FYI JPA has no such method names. That is Spring Data JPA, a totally different API

Comment: You can use `@Query` . Can you post your `Cert10Total` entity property.

Comment: try passing 4 parameters eg,
List<Cert10Total> findAllByCreatedDateOrUpdatedDateBetween(Date dateFrom1, Date dateTo1,Date dateFrom2, Date dateTo2);

Comment: @SudhirOjha what makes you think that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can like this:

`List<Cert10Total> findByDateGermBetweenOrDatePurityBetween(Date germStart, Date germEnd, Date purityStart, Date purityEnd);`

General style is that each conjunction(between and or in your case) is appended with the param that is passed.
But in all the fairness, I think you should use a query instead as it's more readable than a such a lengthy method name and misplace param values for callers